# Is it poosible to open the same file using wfstream and fstream

Tags: c++, file

Actually i have a requirement wherein i need to open the same file using wfstream file instance at one part of the code and open it using fstream instance at the other part of the code. I need to access a file where the username is of type std::wstring and password is of type std::string. how do i get the values of both the variables in the same part of the code?
 Like you can see below i need to get the values for username and password from the file and assign it to variables.
type conversion cannot be done. Please do not give that solution.
......file.txt.......

username-amritha
password-rajeevan

the code is written as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{


std::string y;
unsigned int l;
std::wstring username;
std::wstring x=L"username";
std::wstring q;
std::string password;
std::string a="password";



std::cout<<"enter the username:";
std::wcin>>username;
std::cout<<"enter the password:";
std::cin>>password;
std::wfstream fpp("/home/aricent/Documents/testing.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out );

std::getline(fpp,q);
if (q.find(x, 0) !=  std::string::npos) {

        std::wstring z=q.substr(q.find(L"-") + 1) ;
        std::wcout<<"the username is:"<<z; 
        fpp.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg ); 
            fpp<<q.replace(x.length()+1, z.length(), username); 



}

    fpp.close();
    std::fstream fp("/home/aricent/Documents/testing.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out );
    std::getline(fp,y);

if (y.find(a, 0) !=  std::string::npos)
 {

        unsigned int len=x.length()+1;
        unsigned int leng=username.length();
        l=len+leng;
        fp.seekg(l+1); 
        std::string b=y.substr(y.find("-") + 1) ;            
        fp<<y.replace(a.length()+1, b.length(), password);     

    }
    fp.close();
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to read the wide-character data as bytes and convert them to wide characters with the [Localization library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale) included in the standard library. To which C++ standard does your library adhere and between which character encodings do you need to convert? A valid response might be: an arbitrary, default system locale to the wide character encoding of the compiler and standard library. I'll try to write an answer based on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's [not recommended](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/FIO21-CPP.+Do+not+simultaneously+open+the+same+file+multiple+times) to open multiple streams to a same file simultaneously. On the other hand, if you don't write to the file, but only read (and thus, would be using `ifstream` and `wifstream`), that's probably safe.

Alternatively, you can simply open a `wfstream`, read the username, close the stream, open a `fstream` and read the password.

If you have the choice, avoid mixed encoding files entirely.

Comment: i tried doing the above but couldnt do it. Moreover, i need to replace the value of the password in the file according to user input. so is it possible. can u please write a small code for doing the same.

Comment: Then use my suggestion to not open the streams at the same time. If you have trouble with it, show us what you tried and we can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @user3803112 in your code, you never have two streams simultaneously open, so that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to open the same file with two descriptors. Even if it worked (read only mode for example), both descriptors would not be synchronised, so you would read first characters on one, and next same characters on second.

So IMHO, you should stick to one single solution. My advice is to use a character stream to process the file, and use a `codecvt` to convert from a narrow `string` to a wide `wstring` when you need it.

An example conversion function could be (ref: [cplusplus.com: codecvt::in](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/in/)):

```
std::wstring wconv(const std::string& str, const std::locale mylocale) {
    // define a codecvt facet for the locale
    typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,std::mbstate_t> facet_type;
    const facet_type& myfacet = std::use_facet<facet_type>(mylocale);

    // define a mbstate to use in codecvt::in
    std::mbstate_t mystate = std::mbstate_t();

    size_t l = str.length();

    const char * ix = str.data(), *next; // narrow character pointers
    wchar_t *wc, *wnext;   // wide character pointers

    // use a wide char array of same length than the narrow char array to convert
    wc = new wchar_t[str.length() + 1];

    // conversion call
    facet_type::result result =  myfacet.in(mystate, ix, ix + l,
        next, wc, wc + l, wnext);
    // should test for error conditions

    *wnext = 0; // ensure the wide char array is properly null terminated

    std::wstring wstr(wc); // store it in a wstring
    delete[] wc;           // destroy the char array
    return wstr;
}
```

This code should test for abnormal conditions, and use try catch to be immune to exceptions but it is left as exercise for the reader :-)

A variant of the above using `codecvt::out` could be used to convert from wide string to narrow string.

In above code, I would use (assuming `nconv` is the function using `codecvt::out` to convert from wide string to narrow string):

```
...
#include <locale>
...
std::cin>>password;
std::locale mylocale;
std::fstream fp("/home/aricent/Documents/testing.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out );

std::getline(fp,y);
q = wconv(y, mylocale);
...
    fp<<nconv(q.replace(x.length()+1, z.length(), username));
}
std::getline(fp, y);
...
```

Comment: can u please use it in my program and show me? I'm still not clear.